# Azure Media Service REST API error MissingApiVersionParameter

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am trying setup media service pipeline via rest services  using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-rest

**Section : Encode remote file stream video – REST**

We are getting an error at mentioned Step : Create an output asset

As per documentation

*https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/:subscriptionId/resourceGroups/:resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/:accountName/assets/:assetName?api-version={{api-version}}*

Endpoint  that we generaetd: *https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/xxxxx/assets/xxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2018-08-01*

Even if we give api version as 2.1, 2.2 etc …. Then also error is same.

response error :

{

```
"error": {

    "code": "MissingApiVersionParameter",

    "message": "The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In [REST v2 the API versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/azure-media-services-rest-api-reference) were 2.0 through 2.19, current.  But in the REST v3 the API the released version is 2018-07-01.  See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/createorupdate.

Answer (score 0):

Also, download the Postman Collection for V3 and look at the URLs. Make sure that you are formatting them properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-rest-apis-with-postman
Use the Postman Console to see the full URL post (open via Alt-CTL-C)

Typical create Asset call would look like:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/:subscriptionId/resourceGroups/:resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaServices/:accountName/assets/:assetName?api-version={{api-version}}

"/assets?api-version=2018-07-01" is an example